# Fail to Pass Data Ionic 2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I am working on an ionic project, where I have a json file with prepared data. For the first page it loads the list where a user select one item in a list to show its content. There is where am getting "Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL"

This is my provider

```
  // geting names deatils
   getNamesDetails(title: string): Observable<Names[]> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.namesUrl}/{title}`)
        .map(
          (res) => <Names[]>res.json()
        )
   }
```

Class for passing my data to the next page using navParam.

```
  detailPage(title: string){
    this.navCtrl.push(NameDetails, {title});
  }
```

For my second screen view is

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      <!--Details-->
      {{ title }}
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="aboutUs()">
        <ion-icon ios="ios-options-outline" md="md-options"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header >
      <strong>{{title}}</strong> 
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{text}}
      <p end><i>{{verse}}</i></p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

My Json files structure is

```
[
    {

        "title": "some title",
        "text": "some text",
        "verse": "some text"

    }
 ]
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you obtaining the information from the json file but passing it as parameter is not working?

Comment: Stack snippets are for *runnable* code. Your examples are not runnable.

Comment: @sebaferreras made the changes. for the title shows but the other 2 does not work. when I inspect in chrome dev tool "http://localhost:8100/data/names.json/%7Btitle%7D 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @FelixKling I was not able to show all the code with the code tab, I preferred using code snipet.

Comment: Formatting code is easy: Insert code, select all the code and press CTRL+K . See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: Thanks @felixKling

Comment: I think the url used to get the data is wrong... `${this.namesUrl}/{title}` gets resolved as `...names.json/title` which does not seem to be a valid file... try with just `this.http.get(this.namesUrl)...`

Comment: @sebaferreras am using es6 template literal ${this.namesUrl} only it works and passes the all object in the son file. was adding the this second argument to that it can select from the son file, but it slaps me with no data found error 404.

Comment: @GeraldBrigen that's because you can't do that... if you append something to the name of the file, that is not going to be a valid file name and that's why you're getting the 404

Comment: @sebaferreras I was able to figure out a solution which I have posted below.

Answer (score 0):

After long trial and error I was able to figure out a solution.

Provider

```
   getNamesDetails(): Observable<Names[]> {
     return this.http.get(`${this.namesUrl}`)
        .map(
          (res) => <Names[]>res.json()
        )
   }
```

Method for passing data to the next page.

```
  detailPage(event, name: Names[]){
    console.log(name);
    this.navCtrl.push(NameDetails, {
      name: name
    })

  }
```

Second page view.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card >
    <ion-card-header >
      <strong>{{name.title}}</strong> 
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{name.text}}
      <p item-right><em>{{name.verse}}</em></p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

On the second page constructor class, I call the `get`

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              private http: Http, 
              private dataService: DataService,
              private navParams: NavParams) {
                this.name = this.navParams.get('name')
              }
```